# using firefinder xpath to find elements

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm using xPath with FireFinder.. but can't seen to get the right xPath to find an element..  Sample html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="ViewContact('9498')" value="View Contact" class="FormButton">
<input type="button" onclick="ViewContact('9499')" value="View Contact" class="FormButton">
```

I can find both of these with:

```
//input[contains(@value,'View Contact')]
```

But if I want to find just one via the id, like:

```
//input[contains(@onclick,'ViewContact('9498')')]
```

won't work, I assume the apostrophes aren't escaped right.. tried without them:

```
//input[contains(@onclick,'ViewContact(9498)')]
```

This works:

```
//input[contains(@onclick,'9498') and contains(@onclick,'ViewContact')]
```

but i'd rather not have to use 2 clauses..  any way to do this in one contains ?

---

Duh...Thanks :) At least I didn't use my login :)

Any tools that can help figure this out instead of stubling around trying things ?

Comment: so why don't you escape the single quote then?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this XPath:

```
//input[contains(@onclick,"ViewContact('9498')")]
```